# Writer's Website -- Feedback needed

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, websites

I've been writing fiction off and on for a number of years and lately I've been more off than on. But I want to get back into writing books and to do that I thought I'd need a website (rather than just a blog, which I had previously).

So, what I'm after is feedback on my effort, which I created a few months ago and then left to languish. Is there enough information on there? Too much writing? Does it look OK? Too brown?

Any and all suggestions will be appreciated!

My writing site is [AKDawson.com](http://www.akdawson.com/)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Andrew*! Please note that we are not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site dedicated to answering generic questions that might benefit other people who might at some point have a similar question. As such the community decided that critique requests are off-topic. You can use your writing as an *example* to illustrate a point, but we are not giving you specific critique, especially not for off-site writing. Therefore I am voting to close your question as off-topic. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry Andrew, but we don't do writing critiques here, as it's just not practical with the Q&A format. See the linked [meta] discussion for a more in-depth reasoning. However, if you have *specific, generally applicable* questions where some of your writing can be used as examples, then there's a good chance we can help; see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in our [help].

Comment: Site looks decent - needs updated content, crosslinks to other relevant sites / writer's communities / purchase portals. Perhaps more overall ballyhoo...

Comment: @Andrew a better question might be: what sort of content should a writer's website have? That's generic enough to benefit other participants. You'd also need bounds for such a question, so as to make it narrow enough to be properly answerable.

Comment: Ah! Thanks everyone for letting me know how StackExchange works and for the feedback. :)